# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document with the chrome web driver

Tags: python, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

I have already read a lot of threads dealing with this issue in the afternoon but I'm currently running short of solutions unfortunately :(

I try to scrape this website: https://www.kumon.co.uk/find-a-tutor/

I use this code in order to store every url of the different stores. To do so I have to iterate on the next page till the last page.

Here is the code I use:

```
def get_urls(url) -> list:
    # Get all URLs to the store pages
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    path_chromedriver = Path(__file__).parent.parent.joinpath('externals/chromedriver')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(str(path_chromedriver), chrome_options=options)
    browser.get(url)
    inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("centre_search")
    inputElement.send_keys('london')
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    store_url = []
    links = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Choose Centre')
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute('href')
        store_url.append(href)
    while browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li[last()]/a/small"):
            WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pagination']//li[last()]/a/small"))).click()
            links = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Choose Centre')
            for link in links:
                href = link.get_attribute('href')
                store_url.append(href)
    return store_url
```

Unfortunately I get a

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

To use a Try... Except is not a good solution, I'm looking for a robust solution.
Should I switch from Chrome to Firefox ?

Thank's in advance,
Nicolas.

Comment: Without `try`/`except` your script execution will be interrupted by exception anyway. Also let us know why use use the same `for` loop twice?

Comment: which of the for loops is failing?

Comment: Coz we have 2 use cases: 1) the first page where we land without iteration 2) every other page reached through iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you think that `try`/`except` is *not good solution*, but this is exactly what you need:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def get_urls(url) -> list:
    # Get all URLs to the store pages
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    path_chromedriver = Path(__file__).parent.parent.joinpath('externals/chromedriver')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(str(path_chromedriver), chrome_options=options)
    browser.get(url)
    inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("centre_search")
    inputElement.send_keys('london')
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    links = browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Choose Centre')
    store_url = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]

    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[last()][not(normalize-space(@class))]/a[@data-page]"))).click()
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(links[-1]))
        except WebDriverException:
            break
        links = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Choose Centre')))
        store_url.extend([link.get_attribute("href") for link in links])
    return store_url
```

Comment: Very good solution, but sometimes it stays stuck on the last page on my side... Infinitely trying to reach the next page(which doesn't exist).

Comment: Hmm... Works fine from my side. It actually should stop as on the last page the Next button is not clickable, so `click()` should raise exception and break the loop... Ok. Try updated answer. I've added `[not(normalize-space(@class))]` predicate to `li` node, so it won't match Next button on the last page (as it contains `class=" disabled"`)